# Can't nail a MySQL query where I require multiple records from a table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

CATEGORIES -- 
entry_id, cat_id

TITLES -- entry_id, title

DATA -- entry_id, date, body

For each record entered into the DB the same entry_id is entered into all three entry_id fields in the three tables.  In the Categories table, it will post a record for each category I've such as:

entry_id: 100 cat_id:24

entry_id: 100 cat_id:31

entry_id: 100 cat_id:17

(say cat_id 24 is web_design, 31 is coding and 17 is ajax)

**THE PROBLEM:** I'm having a bugger of a time selecting only records that have a record for BOTH cat_id 24 and 17 in the Categories table along with other fields.  Here's what I've got.  I know it's crude but it gets me almost all the way there:

```
SELECT 
    data.entry_id,
    data.date,
    data.body,  
    titles.entry_id,
    titles.title AS biz_name,
    categories.entry_id,
    categories.cat_id
    FROM data, titles, categories
    WHERE data.entry_id = titles.entry_id 
    AND data.entry_id = categories.entry_id 
    AND categories.cat_id = '24'
```

This will display everything with a cat_id of 24 but when I add

```
AND categories.cat_id = '17'
```

to the very end of the query, nothing is returned.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by Add? You have check for 24 and 17 both in AND? Can you please put the updated query?

Comment: Methinks he is using a key reference table, he wants to `LEFT JOIN` the categories table so he can check per data that it has two different categories entries. See answer.

Comment: I when I say add I meant that I added that last snippet, which results in no records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
data.entry_id,
data.date,
data.body,  
titles.entry_id,
titles.title AS biz_name,
FROM data
JOIN titles ON data.entry_id = titles.entry_id
INNER JOIN categories cat1 ON data.entry_id = cat1.entry_id AND cat1.cat_id=17
INNER JOIN categories cat2 ON data.entry_id = cat2.entry_id AND cat2.cat_id=24
WHERE ((cat1.cat_id) = (17)) AND ((cat2.cat_id) = (24))
```

This new query correctly filters for only the ones with both

Comment: I believe this answer is on the right track but it's still resulting in zero records.  Could it be my query is only pulling the first matching record in the Categories table instead of all of them for each entry_id match?

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake. Hang on while I fix this.

Comment: Fixed, but you can't select the categories (You already know it's in categories 17 and 24 right?) without getting duplicate entries in the first place (One for every extra category) so I left that out.

Comment: Right, I already know the category numbers.  Unfortunately this is pulling zero records as well.

Comment: Ok, I don't have a clone of your setup (phpmyadmin being a pain) could you consequtively add a line until it stops working so we can see what's wrong? (You do have "titles" that exist in both categories right? doh!)

Comment: Nope, the only thing all tables have in common are the entry_id field. Categories table only have entry_id and cat_id fields (and in case I wasn't clear before) there are many cases in that table where an entry_id is listed multiple times because the post belongs to multiple categories, I.E:
entry_id 250 - cat_id 13
entry_id 250 - cat_id 17
entry_id 250 - cat_id 83

Comment: Could you chop lines off the bottom until it works so we can see what went wrong?

Comment: I dropped the last INNER JOIN and WHERE lines and it returned all records with a category of 17 (4 of them).  So you know, of those 4, 3 have both category 17 and 24 assigned to them.

Comment: Stupid stupid stupid me, the cat1 at the end of the second join and where clause should be cat2, will edit... There, all fixed.

Comment: You, sir, are a rock star!  Worked like a champ!  Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    data.entry_id,
    data.date,
    data.body,  
    titles.entry_id,
    titles.title AS biz_name,
    categories.entry_id,
    categories.cat_id
    FROM data, titles, categories
    WHERE data.entry_id = titles.entry_id 
    AND data.entry_id = categories.entry_id 
    AND categories.cat_id IN (17,24)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add one condition to another you use OR

```
.. AND (categories.id='24' OR categories.id='17';
```

This will include both 24 and 17 in your result

Comment: but I only need to returns results where they are BOTH present for any given record.

Comment: @86Stang one record (tuple) only have one id, right? either '24' or '17' in this case. Your comment suggests that one record can have multiple ids.